# check the length of a pattern that is guaranteed to be repeating

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I realize that this is probably a very beginner level question, but i genuinely cannot think of anything and I couldn't find any similar forum answers, maybe there's a library or something for this?

What I'm imagining is a list of integers that is guaranteed to be repeating at some point but that might end half way through an iteration of the pattern e.g. `[1,2,5 ,1,2,5]` or `[1,2,5 ,1,2,5 ,1,2]` and that you could feed this into a function that could either find the length of the isolated pattern or return one iteration of the pattern itself so this could be done with `len()`. Also just to add to this the pattern could also have multiple appearances of the same number or it may include the entire first few numbers again somewhere else, so you can't just find the start and find when the start is next used in the array.

I understand that this is pretty vague and probably doesn't have any easy solution, but any suggestions or reading material would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please post more sample cases? The one I'm curious about is whether [1,3,2,1,3] would have a pattern of [1,3]. If it wouldn't, I think the itertools module would help(especially itertools.cycle(pattern).

Comment: @a1426 i was thinking that [1,3,2,1,3] could be recognised to be 3 long with 1,3 being the start of a new iteration and not the end of the first although i dont know how this would be possible without a longer array. Also thanks for the reccomendation, i'll read up on itertools a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution with time complexity O(n^2) is like the following:

```py
def get_pattern_length(t):
    for pattern_length in range(1, len(t)):
        for i in range(len(t) - pattern_length):
            if t[i] != t[i + pattern_length]:
                break
        else:
            return pattern_length
    return len(t)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_pattern_length([1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5]))  # prints 3
    print(get_pattern_length([1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2]))  # prints 3
    print(get_pattern_length([1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4]))  # prints 7
```

`get_pattern_length` function tries to check every possible pattern length (from `1` to `len(t) - 1`), and returns the minimum pattern length.

In case of `[1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4]`, there's no repeating pattern in the list. (`1, 2, 5` seems to be repeated at first glance, but it is broken by `4` at the end.) So it treats the full length `len(t)` as the pattern length. That is, it expects the full list would be repeated.

Comment: This looks like exactly what i was thinking of, thanks!